# No access to phpmyadmin

Tags: server, apache2, phpmyadmin

I can't access phpmyadmin. I get this classic forbidden error: You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin on this server. I installed phpmyadmin via apt-get. I choosed apache2 in the installation progress. The first weird thing is, that no phpmyadmin.conf symlink is created in conf.d folder of apache. The next weired thing is, that I can create the symlink myself, restart the apache and the mysql server without any error and get the same forbidden error. The apache.conf from phpmyadmin is the default one. I'm using the user root. Could that be a problem with user:usergroup of some files?

Comment: I could solve the first problem. I didn't know that you have to select apache2 by hitting spacebar in the phpmyadmin installation progress.

Answer (score 0):

I think this one is going to require a reinstall.  I have not had the issue you are describing, however, I have had others.  A complete purge and reinstall has fixed the issue on those occasions.  Some info that would be useful to further troubleshoot this would be the version of Ubuntu you are using.

Comment: It's 12.04 lts. I did several purges and reinstallations actually. Unfortunately it is always the same. Apache, php and mysql are available in clean installations. Am I missing any mods maybe?